# Python 3.8 failed to compile Module _uuid

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, uuid, python-3.8

Compiling the recent version of Python 3.8, the UUID module failed with this following error:

```
/home/centos/Python-3.8.0/Modules/_uuidmodule.c: In function ‘py_uuid_generate_time_safe’:
/home/centos/Python-3.8.0/Modules/_uuidmodule.c:19:5: error: unknown type name ‘uuid_t’
     uuid_t uuid;
     ^
/home/centos/Python-3.8.0/Modules/_uuidmodule.c:36:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘uuid_generate_time’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     uuid_generate_time(uuid);
     ^
/home/centos/Python-3.8.0/Modules/_uuidmodule.c:37:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     return Py_BuildValue("y#O", (const char *) uuid, sizeof(uuid), Py_None);
                                 ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

I installed all relevant packages without any issue.

Comment: do you have libuuid-devel installed?

Comment: I am on centos 7 ,  uuid-devel is installed

Comment: I fixed this issue by removing uuid-devel package, and installing the other one libuuid-devel as Luis told me. Run the `.configure` command again to create a correct makefile and then `make` command, the error will be gone.

Comment: re-running `./configure` after installation of `uuid-dev` on ubuntu helped me as well

Answer (score 4):

please install lzma devel lib and uuid devel lib. uuid was linked to this lib.
`sudo apt-get install uuid-dev lzma-dev liblzma-dev`

didn't install:

[_uuid build failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI5jr.png)

after `sudo apt-get install uuid-dev lzma-dev liblzma-dev` install:

[_uuid _lzma is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFVKq.png)